# Sample code for receiving and decoding MMS/mm7 in java aplication

Tags: java, mms

We are working the MMS application using mm7 protocol. We are able to send the MMS using instacom application.Got the sample code form the below link:
**https://github.com/vnesek/instantcom-mm7/commit/272469a13be7d61899520e981d347d03113652f4**.Is there any sample for receiving the MMS in java ?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a servlet that extends AbstractMM7Servlet and implement the dispatch method

```
protected MM7Response dispatch(MM7Request req) throws MM7Error {
    MM7Response resp = new MM7Response();
    if (req instanceof SubmitReq) {
        SubmitReq submitReq = (SubmitReq) req;
        // do your logic
    } else {
        throw new MM7Error("method not supported");
    }
    return resp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. We have received the request using the code you shared.But we are not able to parse the incoming submit request using INSTACOM sample code.Please help us on this.